# How many terms in the series $arctan(x)$ would be needed to get $\pi\ $to the $10$th decimal place?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I got $\pi=\frac 41-\frac 43+\frac 45-\frac 47+\frac 49\ldots$ but I can see that using this it will take me a very long time to reach the decimal expansion I'm looking for. I thought about setting $(-1)^n\frac{1}{2n-1}$ less than $10^{-10}$ but I'm not sure if that is a proper method.

Comment: If you do that, the error will certainly be smaller than ,000... 001, (because of the alternating series property) but you can probably make the error that small with somewhat fewer terms. Are you supposed to find the exact minimum number of terms to get the error that small?

Comment: yes the minimum term to get an error that small

Answer (score 0):

You can gain a little bit of accuracy by taking only half of your last term but the series remains notoriously slow. If you want a series that converges faster tke your pick here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use  *Machin's formula*:
$$\frac\pi4=4\arctan\frac15-\arctan\frac1{239}$$
$7$ terms should be enough.

Comment: is there a way i can approximate the # of terms needed without using this method?